# How to safely modify globals / write files in express POST request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, concurrency

I am writing my first very simple express server for data a collection purpose. This seems like a beginner question but I failed to find an answer so far. The data is very small (less than 500 integers) and will never grow, but it should be able to be changed through POST requests.

I essentially (slightly simplified) want to:

- Have the data in a .json file that is loaded when the server starts.
- On a POST request, modify the data and update the .json file.
- On a GET request, simply send the .json containing the data.

I don't want to use a database for this as the data is just a single small array that will never grow in size. My unclarities are mainly how to handle modifying the global data and file reading / writing safely, i.e. concurrency and how exactly does Node run the code.

I have the following

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');

let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json'));

const app = express();
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./data.json', { root: __dirname });
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  const client_data = req.body;
  // modify global data
  fs.writeFileSync("./data.json", JSON.stringify(data), "utf8");
});
```

Now I have no idea if or why this is safe to do. For example, modifying the global `data` variable and writing to file. I first assumed that requests cannot run concurrently without explicitly using async functions, but that seems to not be the case: I inserted this:

```js
const t = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5000);
while(t > new Date()){}
```

into the `app.post(..` call to try and understand how this works. I then made simultaneous POST requests and they finished at the same time, which I did not expect.

Clearly, the callback I pass to `app.post(..` is not executed all at once before other POST requests are handled. But then I have a callback running concurrently for all POST requests, and modifying the global `data` and writing to file is unsafe / a race condition. Yet all code I could find online did it in this manner.

Am I correct here? If so, how do I safely modify the data and write it to file? If not, I don't understand how this code is safe at all?

Comment: I wouldn't call it safe, you're definitely open to causing race conditions and corrupting the file; Just out of curiosity, you said all the requests finished at the same time - approximately how long was the delay?

Comment: I didn't measure it, but less than 1 second

Comment: even when you were stopping the code execution for 5 seconds?

Comment: yes, I did two simultaneous POST requests with curl -X POST ... from the terminal with the 5s delay. They both finished simultaneously after 5s.

Answer (score 0):

Code like that actually opens up your system to race conditions. Node actually runs that code in a single-threaded kind of way, but when you start opening files and all that stuff, it gets processed by multiple threads (opening files are not Node processes, they are delegated to the OS).

If you really, really want to use files as your global data, then I guess you can use an operating system concept called Mutual Exclusions. Basically, its a 'lock' used to prevent race conditions by forcing processes to wait while something is currently accessing the shared resource (or if the shared resource is busy). In Node, this can be implemented in many ways, but one recommendation is to use `async-mutex` library to handle concurrent connections and concurrent data modifications. You can do something like:

```js
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const Mutex = require('async-mutex').Mutex;

// Initializes shared mutual exclusion instance.
const mutex = new Mutex()

let data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('./data.json'));

const app = express();
app.listen(3000);
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile('./data.json', { root: __dirname });
});

// Turn this into asynchronous function.
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const client_data = req.body;

  const release = await mutex.acquire();
  try {
    fs.writeFileSync('./data.json', JSON.stringify(data), 'utf8');
    res.status(200).json({ status: 'success' });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ err });
  finally {
    release();
  }
});
```

You can also use `Promise.resolve()` in order to achieve similar results with the `async-mutex` library.

Note that I recommend you to use a database instead, as it is much better and abstracts a lot of things for you.

References:

- [Node.js Race Conditions](https://www.nodejsdesignpatterns.com/blog/node-js-race-conditions/)

Comment: Is there only a race condition for the file handling, not the global variable modifications? Since the POST's seem to run concurrently, I don't see why there need to multiple threads for a race condition? I will probably use mutex for both. Though I don't quite understand how `await mutex.acquire()` is not itself another race condition. Might have to peek the implementation.
A DB while of course good, seems quite overengineered for a single fixed size array.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. `await mutex.acquire()` itself is not another race condition as the instance for it has already been initialized in the top-level code before the requests are processed.